# How to create a new array of set length from multiple arrays of varying length, the number of items taken from each smaller arrays based on importance

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, weighting

I want to pull 'questions' from different 'topic' arrays to build a quiz. The topics are being selected in order of importance to the user, each topic with a varying number of questions within and are used to populate a 20 question quiz's question bank based on their selection.

The most important rated topics will have more questions within this bank of 20 questions. The algorithm to complete this giving me a hard time.

I've tried looping over the parent topics array (containing all of the topic objects with name:str and question:[] properties). Then using an average amount(rounded up in case of odd number of topics) of questions needed to create 20 questions from all the topic's questions I worked out if there is any overhead.

i.e. 6 topics = 3.3 q's from each topic, 4 rounded up which is 24 q's to be pulled = overhead of 4.

Then I am trying to takeaway the overhead from the amount of questions to be pulled from the least important rated topics. The last item in the array being the least important.

```
function createWeightedQuestionBank(topicsArray) {

  // Returned Object of questions.
  let questionsBanks = [];

  // How many questions we want our quiz/question bank to have.
  const questionsLimit = 20;

  // The topics are passed in via the topics Array. Each Topic is an object
  // with {name: "topicName", questions: [q1,q2,q3,q4]}
  const topics = topicsArray;

  if (topics) {

  // The amount of topics in the topics array to be included in the questions banks.
  // TODO: inclusion and exclusion of topics.
  const topicsAmount = topics.length;

  // This is the average amount of questions that should be taken from each group

  // to make 20q's (rounded up).
  const questionsAverage = Math.ceil(questionsLimit / topicsAmount);

  // If an uneven number of topics is selected rounding up is necessary, but not
  // Leaves us with too many questions when the average amount is selected from each group.
  // 20questions/6topics = 4(rounded up from each group). 6*4 = 24.
  const projectedQuestions = (questionsAverage * topicsAmount);

  let overhead;

  if (questionsLimit > projectedQuestions ) {
    overhead = questionsLimit - projectedQuestions;

  } else {
    overhead = projectedQuestions - questionsLimit;
  }

  let overheadVariance = overhead;

  for ( let i = 0; i < topics.length; i++) {
    const topic = topics[i];
    let pullAmount;

    if (topics.length - (overhead - 1) <= i) {
      pullAmount = questionsAverage - (overheadVariance - overhead);
      overheadVariance++;
    } else {
      pullAmount = questionsAverage;
    }
    console.log(topics.length - (overhead));
```

What the topics array looks like.

```
 this.topics = [
      {
        name: 'testy',
        isSelected: false,
        questions:
          [
            'one',
            'two',
            'three',
            'one',
            'two',
            'three',
            'four',
          ]
    },
      {
        name: 'testy1',
        isSelected: false,
        questions:
          [
            'one',
            'one',
            'one',
            'one',
            'two',
            'three',
            'four',
          ]
    },
      {
        name: 'test2',
        isSelected: false,
        questions:
          [
            'one',
            'two',
            'three',
            'four',
          ]
    },
      {
        name: 'testy3',
        isSelected: false,
        questions:
          [
            'one',
            'two',
            'three',
            'four',
          ]
    },
      {
        name: 'testy4',
        isSelected: false,
        questions:
          [
            'one',
            'two',
            'three',
            'four',
          ]
    },
      {
        name: 'testy5',
        isSelected: false,
        questions:
          [
            'one',
            'two',
            'three',
            'four',
          ]
    },
    ];
```

I can't figure out how to get remove the overhead of 4 from the last 3 topic question arrays. So instead of pulling 4 (the average amount to be pulled to make 20) I would pull 3 2 1 from the three least important topics.

I want the output to be 4 4 4 3 2 1 totaling 20. 
However it just logs 2 six times.

Comment: This is a little confusing. I notice you set `const topic = topics[i]` but then never use it. Can you maybe give an example with fewer "topics"?

Comment: The topic variable is never used as I am stuck on trying to figure out how many q's should be pulled from each individual topic. In this example I am trying to get the output of the loop(ie # of q's to be pulled) to be 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2. Once that number is achieved I would use it to loop over the topics and pull that amount of q's from the topic into the question bank each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `4+4+4+3+2+1` is `18`, not `20` =)

If you need something like `4+4+4+4+3+1`, you can try:

```js
const amountOfTopics = topics.length;
const questionsPerTopic = Math.ceil(questionsLimit / amountOfTopics);
const overhead = questionsPerTopic * topics.length - questionsLimit;
const maxQuestionsCanBeRemoved = questionsPerTopic - 1;
const singleQuestionTopics = Math.floor(overhead / maxQuestionsCanBeRemoved);
const restQuestionsToBeRemoved = overhead - singleQuestionTopics * maxQuestionsCanBeRemoved;

const getAmountOfQuestions = topicIndex => {
  if (topicIndex >= amountOfTopics - singleQuestionTopics) {
    return 1;
  }

  if (topicIndex === amountOfTopics - singleQuestionTopics - 1) {
    return questionsPerTopic - restQuestionsToBeRemoved;
  }

  return questionsPerTopic;
};

topics.flatMap(
  (topic, index) => {
    const amount = getAmountOfQuestions(index);

    return topic.questions.slice(0, amount);
  }
);
```